# Get Other Label (synonym), description property values of a term set using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api, term-set, flow

I am working with the Microsoft Flow where I need to get the **OtherLabel** and **description** property values of a term-set. This term set is attached as file metadata in a document library.
I tried, there is no activity that returns this data. I logged the result object as string but no info on these 2 property. So I am thinking retrieve this data using REST api. Any help appreciated !!

Edit1: Screen attached
[image]

PS: I know it is possible using JSOM but as per my knowledge, Microsoft flow doesn't allow to write scripts within it.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Any clue will be appreciated ! Deadline is approching